# Alternate two different custom cell layouts in a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, custom-cell

In my storyboard I created two different prototype cells, cell1 and cell2. I want them to appear in my tableView like this:

TableView

```
prototype cell1 - indexpath.row[0]
prototype cell2 - indexpath.row[1]
prototype cell1 - indexpath.row[2]
prototype cell2 - indexpath.row[3]
and so on...
```

I experimented with `if` and `switch` statements and `for` loops in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but couldn't get it right. Then I searched here and on the internet but still couldn't find an answer. Hopefully someone could explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple to do with the mod operator and a single if statement,

```
if (indexPath.row %2 == 0) {
    //dequeue cell1 type
    // configure the cell
    // return cell

}else{
    //dequeue cell2 type
    // configure the cell
    // return cell
}
```